# PHP Variables to Backbone.js model

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-model

I have a backbone.js model

I also have a php form with a particular string stored in a  `$_GET[value]` .  I need to pass that string to a backbone model and update the values in the backbone variable with the value from the php variable.

Comment: What did you try to do so far?

Comment: Seems like some mere AJAX & JSON thing. As namero999 asked, what did you try?

Comment: to be honest with you its more that I do not know where to start....i do not know where to look

Answer (score 0):

The value of your PHP Variable needs to be in your rendered page somewhere so that you can put it into a backbone model.

If you're trying to store the value via `backbone.sync`, that's a different story.

Posting some of your own code will probably get you a more direct answer.